# bar chart with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create a bar chart with `pgfplots`.
My code is similar to [example](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/bar-plot/) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        enlargelimits=0.15,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ylabel=something,
        symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical}]
        \addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
        \legend{used,understood,not understood}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[TODO]{TODO}
    \label{label}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

> finished with exit code 1.

- Does that code give a bar chart if you run it?
- What could be the reason that it does not work for me?
- Wrong `pgfplots` version?

My output looks like this:

[image]

For each entry in `coordinates` I get

> Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'tool8' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'tool8'..

I use Xubuntu 12.04 with Kile 2.1.0 and `\pgfversion` 2.10

Update:

If I remove the `symbolic x coords` it works fine. If I replace the `toolx` by a number I get:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/symbolic x coords' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: what is the rest of the error? Which system? What is your pgfplots version? I get the correct result.

Comment: @percusse : I edited the question and included the answers to your questions.

Comment: Yes, both your pgfplots and tikz versions are outdated. You need to update your packages.

Comment: thank you for your comments, I assumed that to be the problem. However I failed when I tried to update it, thats another question maybe.. For now the workaround I postet is sufficient for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As percusse pointed out the problem might be outdated versions of tikz and pgfplots.

However I got the result I wanted by a workaround:

file `data.txt` :

```
1, 99
2, 120
3, 80
```

tex code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
      \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        xmin=0.5,
        xmax=3.5,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        bar width=1cm, 
        xlabel={something else},
        xlabel style={yshift=-1cm},
        xtick align=inside,
        xticklabels={one bar, another bar , third bar},
        ylabel={something},
        x tick label style={font=\normalsize, rotate=45, anchor=east}
        ]
        \addplot table [x index=0,y index=1, col sep=comma] {data.txt};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[TODO]{TODO}
    \label{label}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

result :

[image]